# Updating Database table from another machine

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

I am trying to update my database using a batch file. Batch file is located on machine say ABC which should pick a text file from the local directory on ABC and upload that file to DATABASE located on say XYZ machine.

I am getting an error as

```
If you are using a remote database server, verify it has access to remote_basedir.

ERROR>:   Error is: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-29913: error in executing    ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ERROR>: ORA-29400: data cartridge error
ERROR>: KUP-04040: file testfile.txt in TEST_9F86D0818 not found
```

I am calling schedules created in NAVICAT to upload .txt files to DATABASE.

Comment: Please show us the complete source code of your stored procedure ([edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it, do **not** post code in comments)

Comment: it seems that the database looks for a file named testfile.txt in the Oracle directory object TEST_9F86D0818. What is the os-path of TEST_9F86D0818 on the database server. Does it contain the file testfile.txt?

Comment: there is a oracle support note "ORA-29913: Error in Executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN Callout (Doc ID 458620.1)"

Comment: The file testfile.txt must ve accessible from the database server. If it resides on a local direcoty of the server ABC this will not work if this directroy is not accessible by the database server. e.g  if it is shared by NFS to the database server it can accessed by the database.

Comment: testfile.txt is on machine ABS where batch file is located. And database server is on XYZ machine. Hope this input helps.

Comment: And what does the batch job do? Can you add the relevant code to your post?

Comment: Code wont be able to post because its a third party batch file. But its responsible for downloading zips from ftp, unzip them and upload the unzipped content to database. These zip files are downloaded to local directory on machine ABC and Uploaded to database located on XYZ machine. Local directory on ABC is made accessible to XYZ user. I think i need to made accessible to database user. tried creating directory in DB and gave complete access access to DB User. But still facing same error.

Comment: What means "uploaded to the database"?

Comment: Zip files have .txt files. They are uploaded to database tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Oracle Support Note [ORA-29913: Error in Executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN Callout (Doc ID 458620.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/458620_1.html)  related to your errormessages. You have an external table (ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL) with data in the file 'testfile.txt'  in the Oracle directory "TEST_9F86D0818".

The support note says that this will happen if your os directories that contain the file testfile.txt does not have the appropriate permissions.

So let's check if this file does not exist or if there are problems with the os permissions on the file or the os directories where it resides.

1. Find out the path of the Oracle directory "TEST_9F86D0818"

   ```
   select directory_path
   from all_directories
   where directory_name='TEST_9F86D0818';
   ```
2. Assume the directory_path retrieve in 1 is '/u01/app/oracle/data' or 'C:\u01\app\oracle\data' if you are on a Windows system. Then login to the database server and check if '/u01/app/oracle/data/testfile.txt' (C:\u01\app\oracle\data\testfile.txt) exists.
3. Let's assume the user that runs your Oracle Software on your database server is `oracle`. Usually this is the case on a Linux server. Then check if this user can read testfile.txt:

   ```
   head /u01/app/oracle/data/testfile.txt > /dev/null
   ```

   or

   ```
   type C:\u01\app\oracle\data\testfile.txt > NUL
   ```

   if you are on a Windows system.
   If this generates an error message then this is the reason for your problem that you have to eliminate.
4. With a user that has access to directory and can execute th UTIL_FILE package (e.g. a dba user) connect to the databae with sqlplus and execute the following 
   command:

   ```
   DECLARE 
     V1 VARCHAR2(32767); 
     F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
   BEGIN 
     F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TEST_9F86D0818','testfile.txt','R'); 
     UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1); 
     UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
   exception 
     when others then
       dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: ' || SQLCODE 
         || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
       raise;
   END;
   /
   ```

   If an error is rased, this is the reason for your problem that you have to eliminate. If no error is raised show us the create statement of your external table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if you could update the answer for Microsoft OS because i am using the same.